# Unable to display content on click on a service in React

Tags: reactjs

**I am trying to add a div with an image on click on a particular service among a list of services , I am pretty new to React , could anyone please guide me through this, I would be grateful.**

```
    var ServiceChooser = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return { total: 0 };
    },

    addTotal: function (price) {
        this.setState({ total: this.state.total + price });
    },

    render: function () {
        var self = this;

        var services = this.props.items.map(function (s) {
            // Create a new Service component for each item in the items array.
            // Notice that I pass the self.addTotal function to the component.

            return <Service name={s.name} price={s.price} active={s.active} addTotal={self.addTotal}/>;
        });

        return <div>
            <h1>Our services</h1>

            <div id="services">
                {services}
                <p id="total">Total <b>${this.state.total.toFixed(2)}</b></p>
            </div>

        </div>;

    }
});
```

### ** This is a service which gets called when on a click on a particular service**

```
 var Service = React.createClass({

        getInitialState: function () {
            return {
                active: false,
                showdetails: false
            };
        },

        clickHandler: function () {

            var active = !this.state.active;
            this.setState({ active: active });
            // Notify the ServiceChooser, by calling its addTotal method
            this.props.addTotal(active ? this.props.price : -this.props.price);

            //showdetails = true;

           // console.log(this.props.name);
            return <Details name={this.props.name} price={this.props.price} showdetails={true}/>;
        },

        render: function () {
            return <p className={this.state.active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.clickHandler}>
                {this.props.name} <b>${this.props.price.toFixed(2)}</b>
            </p>;
        }

    });



var services = [
    { name: 'Web Development', price: 300 },
    { name: 'Design', price: 400 },
    { name: 'Integration', price: 250 },
    { name: 'Training', price: 220 }
];

// Render the ServiceChooser component, and pass the array of services

React.render(
    <ServiceChooser items={services} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind `this` to your component methods. This can be done this way (for example):

```
return <Service name={s.name} price={s.price} active={s.active} addTotal={self.addTotal.bind(this)} />;
```

Additionally, I'm not quite sure if

```
this.props.addTotal(active ? this.props.price : -this.props.price);
```

throws an error, because of the prefixed `-`. I would prefer something like `this.props.price * -1` instead of.